# SubMenu abrindo no local errado

Tags: html, css, html5, menu, nav-bar

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Menu">V11 Web</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#textoNavbar" aria-controls="textoNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="textoNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="MenuPrincipal1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Arquivos<span class="sr-only">(Página atual)</span></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="MenuPrincipal1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="MenuPrincipal2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Editar<span class="sr-only">(Página atual)</span></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="MenuPrincipal2">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="MenuPrincipal3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cadastros<span class="sr-only">(Página atual)</span></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="MenuPrincipal3">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="navbar-text text-white">
            <span class="sublinhado">Usuário</span>:gerente
        </span>

        <button id="sair" type="button" onclick="location.href = '/';" class="btn btn-outline-light espaco-esq">Sair</button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um código utilizando o HTML, e eu fui criar uma `nav-bar`, mas não está saindo como eu gostaria.

Eu tenho os itens de um menu, e todos, eles, ao clicar, abrirão um submenu, por enquanto todos os submenus tem o mesmo conteúdo. Mas ao clicar para abrir o submenu, ele não está abrindo no local certo... ele abre como se estivesse com um `float: left;`. Vou deixar um print pra vcs... eu gostaria que ele abrisse de acordo com o item clicado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que no 1º print, o item clicado foi "Arquivos", enquanto no 2º print o item clicado foi "Pesquisas", mas os dois foram abertos no mesmo lugar. Me ajudem por favor.

Comment: Consegue elaborar um [mcve]? Da forma que está não conseguimos reproduzir o problema.

Comment: vou criar aqui, so um minuto @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Ta usando qual versão do Bootstrap?

Comment: versão 4.3.1 @hugocsl

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, acho que assim está adequado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua `LI` da `Nav` que tem o Sub-Menu faltou a classe `.dropdown`. Ela deveria estar assim

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
```

Veja corrigido, **execute em página toda**, para ver o menu sem ele estar *collapsado*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
 
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Menu">V11 Web</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#textoNavbar" aria-controls="textoNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="textoNavbar">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <!-- @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MenuPrincipal.Count; i++)
    { -->
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="MenuPrincipal_@i" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button" >@Model.MenuPrincipal[i]<span class="sr-only">(Página atual)</span></a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="MenuPrincipal_@i">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    <!-- } -->
   </ul>
   <span class="navbar-text text-white">
    <span class="sublinhado">Usuário</span>
    <!-- : @HttpContext.Session.GetString("Usuário") -->
   </span>
 
   <button id="sair" type="button" onclick="location.href = '/';" class="btn btn-outline-light espaco-esq">Sair</button>
  </div>
 </nav>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: funcionou... obrigado

Comment: @SamuelMachado legal que resolveu! Sempre consulte a documentação :) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/